# API architecture - output consistent data in SI units or intelligently adapt to return user friendly data and units

Tags: api, restful-architecture

Two scenarios - an API that consistently outputs data in SI units. So if a device is transmitting 0.0001V you will get that same output. If it posts 1000W then again it will return 1000W. Any sanitization to make the data more user friendly will need to be done by the application making the get requests. Potentially many applications will require user friendly data.

The alternative approach would be for intelligence to be coded within the API to effectively make the output data user friendly. So if a device posts 10000W then the user will get 10kW output. Basically if a figure can be best represented using less digits but with a more appropriate unit then the API will figure that out and return that data. So the data output is not consistent but depends on the values themselves.

In terms of designing a RESTful API and best practices,  which method is more appropriate and why? The argument is is that since many applications will require user friendly data, the idea would be to save time and energy to do it once in the back-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do both. Include the actual numerical value, the unit, and the user-friendly value as three separate properties in the response.

Comment: It's definitely an option, but in terms of best practices and consistency is the user friendly version in line with these for a restful api?